# Creating well defined logic formulas of implications

Tags: logic

Is the following statement true? :

> if $A$ is a well-defined formula and $A$ implies that $B$ is a well-defined formula, then $A \implies B$ is a well-defined formula

As an example
For some $x$,

- $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is a well-defined formula
- if $x \in \mathbb{N}$, then we can verify that $\operatorname{mcd}(x, 1) = 1$ is a well-defined formula (if $x \notin \mathbb{N}$, the function $\operatorname{mcd}$ has no clear meaning)

Then, is $x \in \mathbb{N} \implies \operatorname{mcd}(x, 1) = 1$   a well-defined formula? why?

Is it possible to get to this final statement using the usual "if $A$ and $B$ are well-defined, then  $A \implies B$  is too"?

Without using that $x \in \mathbb{N}$, it doesn't seem possible to me to assume or prove that $\operatorname{mcd}(x, 1) = 1$ is well-defined.

(By a formula being well-defined, I understand that it has a definitive True or False value, pheraphs my confusion comes from this definition)

Comment: Well-formed means simply: according to the syntactical specifications of the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we formally study logical systems, we usually avoid this issue (which I'd call "conditionally defined notation") by considering every notational construct to have some "dummy value" when its "conditions for being meaningful" are not satisfied.

For example, if you're working in set theory, you could consider $\operatorname{mcd}(x,y)$ to denote the empty set when $x,y$ are not both in $\Bbb N$. When we're actually doing number theory, we're careful only to use $\operatorname{mcd}$ on natural numbers, but in more abstract contexts where we're formalizing what it means to be a well-formed formula, we allow $\operatorname{mcd}(x,y)$ to be a valid [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_(logic)) whenever $x$ and $y$ are valid terms. Because of how $\implies$ works, we know that the truth value of "$x\in\Bbb N\implies(\dots\operatorname{mcd}(x,1)\dots)$" does not depend on our choice of dummy value.